# VECM model unable to predict approximately but able to learn the pattern

Tags: time-series, arima, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

In the below image VECM model has learnt the pattern but did not predict properly there is a difference in actual and prediction

Have used the below dataset to predict the meanpressure:-
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sumanthvrao/daily-climate-time-series-data/code

In what other method we can reduce the difference or is there any other multivariant time series model where it can address the issue. Where with the minimum amount of data the model should use cointegration and predict. So, for that will VECM is suitable? If possible suggest different other methods.

Comment: You presumably could not post a picture because you do not have enough reputation yet, right? You may want to upload the picture at some external hosting service and link to it here. In the meantime, is this perhaps a case of ["my predictions vary less than the actuals"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352)? Especially for ARIMA models, it is quite common that the model follows the actuals quite closely in-sample, and then varies a lot less out-of-sample - which is how it should be.